# How to get bower to install typeahead.js for ASP.NET 5 Application?

Tags: git, bower, asp.net-core, typeahead.js, windows-10

### Problem

According to the instructions for typeahad.js on the git repo. You are suppose to do the following in windows command line (also in root of my asp.net 5 application):

`bower install typeahead.js`

I ended up seeing the following error when I did so.

`bower typeahead#~0.11.1     not-cached git://github.com/twitter/typeahead.git#~0.11.1
bower typeahead#~0.11.1        resolve git://github.com/twitter/typeahead.git#~0.11.1
bower typeahead.js#*            cached git://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js.git#0.11.1
bower typeahead.js#*          validate 0.11.1 against git://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js.git#*
bower typeahead#~0.11.1        ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/twitter/typeahead.git", exit code of #-532462766`

### Attempts

Okay, so maybe this is because of git and not https. So I tried

`config --global ur."https://".insteadOf git://`

It gave me the following error:

`Unsupported command arguments: config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://`

### Note

I am currently going to install the entire zip and put it in a file where I can access it, but has someone previously or can now figure out what might be causing this failure? I tore my hair out for an hour or so but can't figure it out. I am not aware of any firewall or anti-virus issues that could case these things. I am using Window 10 on Hyper-V as well.

I am reaching out to see if anyone else has found a workaround that isn't as hacky as what I am about to do? I would be nice if I could get this to work with bower.

Thanks,

hlyates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. The clue is `unsupported` commands. It seems that the git package that comes with VS15 is not entirely complete. So I went to obtain git [here](http://git-scm.com/download/win). I then ran the command again above and the issue is resolved.